# Trouble with anchor point in CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to get a UIButton to scale but remain at its original center point, and I'm getting perplexing results with CGAffineTransformScale.

Here's the function in my UIButton subclass:

```
-(void)shrink {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

With this code, the button scales to the top-left corner, but when I add code to try to set the anchor point (either of the following lines), the button gets relocated off screen somewhere:

```
[self.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)];
//same result if I use bounds instead of frame
[self.layer setAnchorPoint:self.center];
```

Interestingly, this line causes the view to move down and to the right some distance:

```
[self.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Sorry, I know there are many posts on this topic already but I honestly read and tried at least a dozen and still couldn't get this to work. I'm probably just missing something incredibly simple.

Answer (score 0):

The default anchor point is 0.5, 0.5.  That is why setting it to 0, 0 moves the view down and to the right.  Also, if you don't want the center to move, you need to re-adjust the center after scaling it.

Just readjust its position after shrinking it.

```
-(void)shrink {
    CGPoint centerPoint = self.center;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9,0.9);
    self.center = centerPoint;
}
```

Comment: using exactly that code, it still scales from the top left.